# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__Employer__postal__59FA5E80' on table 'Employer' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have hand coded a database schema (part of which is shown below):

```
CREATE TABLE Employer 
(
   id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   industry_sector_id INTEGER 
      REFERENCES IndustrySector(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,
   name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
   legal_entity_type_id INTEGER 
      REFERENCES LegalEntityType(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,
   size_category_id INTEGER 
      REFERENCES EmployerStaffSizeCategory(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,
   location_address INTEGER 
      REFERENCES ResidentialAddress(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,
   postal_address INTEGER 
      REFERENCES PostalAddress(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxu_employer_name ON Employer(name);
CREATE INDEX idx_employer_industry ON Employer(industry_sector_id);
```

When I execute the query in SSMS, I get the following error message:

> Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 714
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__Employer__postal__59FA5E80' on table 'Employer' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 714
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I can't see what is wrong with the SQL statement (it worked fine with PostgreSQL [and modified slightly, for mySQL too]). Can anyone point out what is the cause of the error message I am getting - I mean which FK is causing the conflict, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the FK referencing the `PostalAddress` table that raises the error. It seems that there is a reference to the same table from both `ResidentialAddress` and `PostalAddress` tables.

There is a MS knowledge base article about this error here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321843

Comment: Yup, I figured out that it was the `postal_address` field causing the problem, after parsing the error message more carefully. Thanks for pointing out the fact that both tables could be referencing the same third table - this is the case. I will amend my Schema accordingly. I'll accept your answer as soon as SO allows me to.